# Can't read Start or End Times with Client Object Model from Calendar in SP 2013

Tags: 2013, javascript, client-object-model

I have some experience using the SharePoint Client Object Model to retrieve text fields and URLs/images from lists in SP 2013. I'm currently trying to do something similar with a calendar. I have been able to successfully retrieve Title and Location fields without any issue, but the Start and End Time fields I am not able to retrieve. I cannot figure out what exactly the issue is. Additionally, I can read Created and Modified with no problems. Here is the relevant code:

```
function retrieveListItemsCal() {
    var clientContextCal = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var oListCal = clientContextCal.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Calendar');
    var camlQueryCal = new SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery();
    AllItemsCal = oListCal.getItems(camlQueryCal);
    clientContextCal.load(AllItemsCal);

    clientContextCal.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceededCal), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailedCal));
}

function onQuerySucceededCal(sender, args) {
    var listItemInfo = '';
    var listItemEnumeratorCal = AllItemsCal.getEnumerator();

    var htmlCal = '';

    htmlCal+="<div id='CalHeader'>Upcoming Events</div>\
    <div id='CalDivider'></div>\
    <div id='CalContainer'>";

    while(listItemEnumeratorCal.moveNext()) {
        var oListItemCal = listItemEnumeratorCal.get_current();

        /*htmlCal+="<div class='CalItem'>\
                "oListItemCal.get_item('Start Time')"\
            </div>";*/
        alert(oListItemCal.get_item("Start Time").format("MMMM d, yyyy"));
    }
    htmlCal+="</div>";

    $("#CalSpace").append(htmlCal);
}

function onQueryFailedCal(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    SP.SOD.executeFunc("sp.js", "SP.ClientContext", retrieveListItemsCal);
});
```

And here is a screenshot of the list columns:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved my issue. I ran the following PowerShell queries (found here http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2012/10/sharepointfinding-column-display-and.html):

```
$web = Get-SPWeb SiteUrl
$list = $web.Lists["Calendar"]
$list.fields | select Title, InternalName, Hidden, CanBeDeleted | sort title | ft -AutoSize
```

The internal names of the Start Time and End Time fields are EventDate and EndDate, respectively.

Answer (score 2):

Check you are using the internal name for these columns.

If you created the column 'Start Time' through the SP GUI, the internal name will end up being 'Start_x0020_Time'.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work for me. The Start Time and End Time columns are automatically generated when you create a Calendar app, if it makes a difference.